# Can I restart Savage Labyrinth at the last checkpoint?

Tags: zelda-wind-waker

I jumped into the Savage Labyrinth to get the triforce piece, but found out I need an item I've not yet gotten to complete it.  Every 10 levels is an exit, but if I take it will I be able to restart at that floor?

*Note: this is on the Wii U version*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the Savage Labyrinth has to be completed in one go. The exit on every 10th level will take you outside but if you go in again you have to start from the first level.